# Insert only digits as input

Tags: jsf

Currently I have a `<h:inputText>`

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{locale.nroEmployees}:"/>
<h:inputText value="#{companyEditBean.companyEmployeesAmount}"
          disabled="#{not companyEditBean.editingAllowed}">
</h:inputText>
```

How can  I achieve, that the user can only type digits in input fields?

Comment: See http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it afterwards to only accept numbers, or do somehting similar to:

```
<h:inputText value="#{companyEditBean.companyEmployeesAmount}"
      disabled="#{not companyEditBean.editingAllowed}"
      onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"/>
```

Comment: what i did,
function isNumberKey(event){
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;          
          if (charCode >= 48){
              if(57 >= charCode){
       return true;
          }}
           return false;
       }

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, you can use primeface for achieving this:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">   
        <h:outputText value="Number Input"/>   
        <h:inputText id="txt_" />   
</h:panelGrid> 
<p:keyFilter for="txt_" mask="num" /> 
</h:form>
```

Or, with primeface extension you can do this (assuming you added required jar and defining extension namespace as pe)

```
<p:inputText id="txt_" required="false" label=""
        value="#{beanclass.blablamethod}" maxlength="10">
        <f:validateLength minimum="10" for="txt_" />
        <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[\d\-]/"></pe:keyFilter>
</p:inputText>
```